# AWS-SAM: build is stuck waiting for lock

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, wsl-2, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to build a container to be deployed at AWS Lambda. Here is the only output I get when running `sam build` (under WSL2):

```
architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
Building image for HelloWorldFunction function
Setting DockerBuildArgs: {} for HelloWorldFunction function
```

It is stuck there. When I abort it, I get:

```
Aborted!
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/aws-sam-cli/1.96.0/dist/threading.pyc'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1553, in _shutdown
  File "concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 31, in _python_exit
  File "threading.py", line 1112, in join
  File "threading.py", line 1132, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

This suggests that it is waiting for a lock called `tstate_lock`. I have restarted WSL2, paused Dropbox, closed VS Code. I can't think of anything that could be holding a lock to any related file. What could be going on and how can I fix it?

**EDIT** I have submitted [an issue at GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/5886).

**UPDATE** I have tried the suggestions of @benlux63 including installing a fresh Ubuntu instance (20.04 LTS), but am still experiencing the issue.

Also, `docker buildx build` is working, so it's not an issue with Docker.

Here is the output of `sam build --debug`:

```
2023-09-05 09:21:27,696 | Config file location:
/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/samconfig.toml
2023-09-05 09:21:27,699 | Loading configuration values from [default.['build'].parameters]
(env.command_name.section) in config file at
'/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/samconfig.toml'...
2023-09-05 09:21:27,700 | Configuration values successfully loaded.
2023-09-05 09:21:27,701 | Configuration values are: {'stack_name': 'wherewasit-embeddings',
'parallel': True}
2023-09-05 09:21:27,708 | Using SAM Template at
/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/template.yaml
2023-09-05 09:21:27,724 | Using config file: samconfig.toml, config environment: default
2023-09-05 09:21:27,725 | Expand command line arguments to:
2023-09-05 09:21:27,725 |
--template_file=/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/template.yaml --parallel
--mount_with=READ --build_dir=.aws-sam/build --cache_dir=.aws-sam/cache
2023-09-05 09:21:27,753 | 'build' command is called
2023-09-05 09:21:27,762 | No Parameters detected in the template
2023-09-05 09:21:27,770 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource
HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-09-05 09:21:27,770 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource
ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-09-05 09:21:27,772 | 0 stacks found in the template
2023-09-05 09:21:27,772 | No Parameters detected in the template
2023-09-05 09:21:27,778 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource
HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-09-05 09:21:27,778 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource
ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the resource id
2023-09-05 09:21:27,779 | 2 resources found in the stack
2023-09-05 09:21:27,780 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and ImageUri='None'
2023-09-05 09:21:27,780 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri ./hello_world relative to
/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/template.yaml
2023-09-05 09:21:27,782 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri . relative to
/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/template.yaml
2023-09-05 09:21:27,796 | 2 resources found in the stack
2023-09-05 09:21:27,796 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and ImageUri='None'
2023-09-05 09:21:27,797 | Error occurred while trying to track an event: Event 'BuildFunctionRuntime'
does not accept value 'None'.
2023-09-05 09:21:27,798 | Instantiating build definitions
2023-09-05 09:21:27,801 | Unique function build definition found, adding as new (Function Build
Definition: BuildDefinition(None, /mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings, Image, ,
00f6b202-7635-400b-a631-ee9ff5f49557, {'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile', 'DockerContext':
'/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/hello_world', 'DockerTag': 'python3.10-v1'},
{}, x86_64, []), Function: Function(function_id='HelloWorldFunction', name='HelloWorldFunction',
functionname='HelloWorldFunction', runtime=None, memory=3000, timeout=30, handler=None, imageuri=None,
packagetype='Image', imageconfig=None,
codeuri='/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings', environment=None, rolearn=None,
layers=[], events={'HelloWorld': {'Type': 'Api', 'Properties': {'Path': '/wherewasit-embeddings',
'Method': 'POST', 'RestApiId': 'ServerlessRestApi'}}}, metadata={'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile',
'DockerContext': '/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/hello_world', 'DockerTag':
'python3.10-v1', 'SamResourceId': 'HelloWorldFunction'}, inlinecode=None, codesign_config_arn=None,
architectures=['x86_64'], function_url_config=None,
function_build_info=<FunctionBuildInfo.BuildableImage: ('BuildableImage', 'Regular IMAGE function
which can be build with SAM CLI')>, stack_path='', runtime_management_config=None))
2023-09-05 09:21:27,812 | Async execution started
2023-09-05 09:21:27,812 | Invoking function functools.partial(<bound method
ParallelBuildStrategy.build_single_function_definition of
<samcli.lib.build.build_strategy.ParallelBuildStrategy object at 0x7ff6a4cb20b0>>,
<samcli.lib.build.build_graph.FunctionBuildDefinition object at 0x7ff6a4cb2350>)
2023-09-05 09:21:27,814 | Building codeuri: /mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings
runtime: None metadata: {'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile', 'DockerContext':
'/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/hello_world', 'DockerTag': 'python3.10-v1'}
architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
2023-09-05 09:21:27,815 | Waiting for async results
2023-09-05 09:21:27,815 | Building to following folder
/mnt/c/Dropbox/Parnasa/Web/temp/wherewasit-embeddings/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction
2023-09-05 09:21:27,817 | Building image for HelloWorldFunction function
2023-09-05 09:21:27,822 | Setting DockerBuildArgs: {} for HelloWorldFunction function
```

The manual keyboard abort results in the same output as in the question above.

Comment: I've seen terraform providers not correctly disposed of by previous sessions before.  You may be able to see this by checking your running processes, or else by using sysinternal's `handle` app to see what's locking the file (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle).  Quickest fix is to try a reboot; if someting is left from an old session, it'll be cleared by the reboot and you may find things start working straight away.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Restarting the laptop did not help...