# Docker image is small after downloading Gigabytes of requirements

Tags: docker

I am just starting with Docker. Here is the output from `docker buildx build .`:

```
[+] Building 510.7s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                       docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 381B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10                                                 2.9s
 => [1/4] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10@sha256:43da8bb9fbf594d92360b822d77ac5c4a2e94363c04f6c607eb285d8  31.6s
 => => resolve public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10@sha256:43da8bb9fbf594d92360b822d77ac5c4a2e94363c04f6c607eb285d8b  0.0s
 => => sha256:d3801952a0b323be41af788db0e371fc8047bcb261f24abfbdde74182c8e0e6d 104.77MB / 104.77MB                23.7s
 => => sha256:43da8bb9fbf594d92360b822d77ac5c4a2e94363c04f6c607eb285d8b26d2883 772B / 772B                         0.0s
 => => sha256:419ce174e84a6b935902356387b3349e04c8b6fd4712663ca2f8fbc77eed2a42 1.58kB / 1.58kB                     0.0s
 => => sha256:ee6bca5d31b2cfc078df15660d552587bbee0e4d6b953e824f0fd400f286d292 3.00kB / 3.00kB                     0.0s
 => => sha256:3fd6848e52b0c56e0d2243cf5be173e348e0de4b893e90a434edafaa8e3bb43a 87.36kB / 87.36kB                   0.6s
 => => sha256:3cb7494b6f02d436b9d61db1ef4aadc0d0d676e43a86fe38493a3ffd01194ab5 417B / 417B                         0.4s
 => => sha256:79a77e7c1be9a2c4f77ead609e8d8b7162377bb6905b2a244c7964d74d8c8762 2.51MB / 2.51MB                     2.7s
 => => sha256:44fd47a7e414290164c13853bdf879e281b3c4d463b97f77e33819e6a0690e8b 64.43MB / 64.43MB                  18.4s
 => => sha256:3faa55ce7fd02aecc32183d9ff5345f31da7cfa458c1bbebaafc25acb126a8aa 12.09MB / 12.09MB                   9.5s
 => => extracting sha256:d3801952a0b323be41af788db0e371fc8047bcb261f24abfbdde74182c8e0e6d                          3.0s
 => => extracting sha256:3fd6848e52b0c56e0d2243cf5be173e348e0de4b893e90a434edafaa8e3bb43a                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:3cb7494b6f02d436b9d61db1ef4aadc0d0d676e43a86fe38493a3ffd01194ab5                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:79a77e7c1be9a2c4f77ead609e8d8b7162377bb6905b2a244c7964d74d8c8762                          0.0s
 => => extracting sha256:44fd47a7e414290164c13853bdf879e281b3c4d463b97f77e33819e6a0690e8b                          2.9s
 => => extracting sha256:3faa55ce7fd02aecc32183d9ff5345f31da7cfa458c1bbebaafc25acb126a8aa                          0.9s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.5s
 => => transferring context: 91.85MB                                                                               0.5s
 => [2/4] COPY app.py requirements.txt ./                                                                          0.5s
 => [3/4] COPY all-MiniLM-L6-v2 ~/.cache/torch/sentence_transformers/sentence-transformers_all-MiniLM-L6-v2        0.1s
 => [4/4] RUN python3.10 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .                                                 441.2s
 => exporting to image                                                                                            34.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                           34.3s
 => => writing image sha256:2e4d6b42a67c9b24318b64dac1f96de88b45af9368ad965249fab73c5d3b8f35                       0.0s
```

The requirements whose installation into the image took over seven minutes is the `sentence-transformers` package with PyTorch and other large dependencies.

Nonetheless, the output of `sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/` is:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 3975 Sep  5 11:30 2e4d6b42a67c9b24318b64dac1f96de88b45af9368ad965249fab73c5d3b8f35
```

How come the image is only 4Kb? Where is the whole environment?

Comment: I *think* what you are looking at is just the image sha and not the last layer (which should be significantly larger). What does `docker inspect` say about your image?

Comment: Do you  mean `docker inspect /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imaged
b/content/sha256/2e4d6b42a67c9b24318b64dac1f96de88b45af9368ad965249fab73c5d3b8f35`? It says `Error: no such object`.

Comment: I've never considered of using `ls` instead of `docker images` to check the size of an image.  Why are you using `ls`?

Comment: @Pino Ah, that's what being a newbie means :) This gives 7.9 GB. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. However a 7.9 GB image is quite big.  Are you sure the Dockerfile cannot be optimized?  Perhaps with a multistage build...

Comment: @Pino Thank you for the suggestion. My goal is to deploy to AWS Lambda and right now I am struggling just to get it to work, as detailed in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77039005/2725810).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/` contains the metadata, not the actual Docker images. You can take a look of an image metadata with:

```
sudo -i
cd /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/
cat <image-sha>
```

So, with your command `ls -l /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256` you're just checking the size of the metadata of the image.

If you want to know the actual size of the image from the command

```
docker images
```

or the size of each layers that compose the image of the container from

```
docker history <image>
```

Comment: What's the container name as opposed to image id? Where do I get it?

Comment: It's the image name, I updated my answer. You get it in 2 ways: 1) with `docker ps -a` under the column IMAGE; 2) with `docker images` merging repository and tag columns like this `REPOSITORY:TAG`