# Cached build with SAM downloads all package dependencies

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am new to the topic and might not be using all the correct terminology, so please forgive it.

I am building a container to be deployed at AWS Lambda. The requirements include the `sentence-transformers` package, which is very large, so that building the docker image takes a long time.

I would like to be able to change the lambda function and rebuild the container as fast as possible, which means avoiding downloading the requirements that have not changed.

Based on my research, I should be able to do this with:

`sam build --cached --beta-features`

However, this does not seem to be working. Namely, all the requirements are being downloaded just like during the very first build. Note that, due to the difficulty discussed in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039005/aws-sam-build-is-stuck-waiting-for-lock#comment135817691_77039965), I had to downgrade to version 1.60.0 of `sam-cli`.

How do I make this work, so that `sam build` should not do the unnecessary work of downloading requirements that were not changed since the last build?

Comment: I’m going to guess one or more of the downvotes are due to the fact “_does not seem to be working_” says absolutely nothing about the problem you’re asking for help with.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was given by the author of [this](https://youtu.be/tL3-PqQvdF4) tutorial. It is to move the dependencies from `requirements.txt` to `Dockerfile`.